# Correct Code Page or Collation in SQL Server for Portuguese characters

Tags: sql-server-2008, collation

I'm inserting data (Bulk insert and merge update) for a Portuguese data source (CSV files) into my database. Although the DB collation is `Latin1-General, case-insensitive, accent-sensitive, kanatype-insensitive, width-insensitive for Unicode Data, SQL Server Sort Order 52 on Code Page 1252 for non-Unicode Data` and data stored in `NVARCHAR` columns, the portuguese charaters are not correctly being saved.

i.e : Original Data

```
Regularização de Importação de mercadorias das ZEEs com Pagamento  diferido, com Isenção
```

Data in database after insert

```
RegularizaÃ§Ã£o de ImportaÃ§Ã£o de mercadorias das ZEEs com Pagamento  diferido, com IsenÃ§Ã£o
```

Here the import statement:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_Import_Temp_CPC] 
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@FilePath [nvarchar](1000)
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

TRUNCATE TABLE Temp_CPC;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
EXEC ('BULK INSERT Temp_CPC
FROM ''' + @FilePath + '''
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ''<,>'', ROWTERMINATOR =''\n'', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPIDENTITY, CODEPAGE = ''ACP'',TABLOCK,ORDER(ITEMID ASC) );');
END
```

I've tried with "ACP,RAW and OEM" but get the same result.

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: `Ã§Ã£` is "Mojibake".  It means that somewhere in the processing, you had not specified `UTF-8`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not going to get the correct result until you tell BULK INSERT **the code page of your .csv file**. You tried ACP, RAW and OEM but you did not try the correct one. Which one is the correct one you ask? That would be something only **you** can answer, since you have the file and you (should) know what code page was originally created as! Perhaps  [MS-DOS Portuguese](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_860)?

the other alternative is to create the .csv file itself as an Unicode file, but that goes back to your source of the .csv file and depends how that file is created (you bcp out, you have it from a friend, was always used by the original program author, etc etc).

> the file is an Unicode one (UTF8 without BOM)

SQL Server [does not support UTF-8 files for bulk insert](http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/370419/bulk-insert-and-bcp-does-not-recognize-codepage-65001). You must save your file as **UCS-2LE** *or* as ASCII with codepage 860. You can use [libiconv](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/libiconv.htm) to do the conversion if you cannot save the file again in the proper encoding.

Comment: Thanks, for the reminder. Unfortunately the file is produced at the client location on a linux box using oracle. And that was default setting i found in used when taking on the project. But im grateful for the conversion library you did provide.

Comment: libiconv also has a command line program: [`iconv`](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libiconv/documentation/libiconv-1.13/iconv.1.html), should be included in the Win32 download.

Comment: And be warned that SQL Server uses UCS2 Little Endian (UCS-2LE).

Answer (score 1):

The [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) statement is using char datatype by default.

You should be using the widechar data type, as mentioned in: [Using Unicode Character Format to Import or Export Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190919%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Mainly, the change should be:

- DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar' if you're using BULK INSERT
- w if you're using BCP

But the original CSV file has to be UNICODE.

Comment: I did apply the changes to the script but got an error 'Bulk load: DataFileType was incorrectly specified as widechar. DataFileType will be assumed to be char because the data file does not have a Unicode signature.' although the file is an Unicode one (UTF8 without BOM), i later converted it to UTF-8 but still got the same results.

Comment: Well, at least you have the evidence that by default it uses char instead of nchar. I'm curious what is a Unicode signature, though.. Maybe I can help with an example.

Comment: A few Googling and it appears that the SQL 2008 support the UTF-16 encoding with the DataType='Widechar'. Upon converting it to  UTF-16 (UCS-2 Big Endian) it did worked.

Comment: Well, it appears that Remus's answer is already clear enough :-).